# Current at the load is zero?

Tags: voltage, current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flmqqb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Based on the way the two voltages sources are placed(in series) the current to the load would be zero since they oppose one another? 
Regardless of the number of branches that are parallel like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIitRl.png)</sup>

Comment: Slide V1 and V2 around their respective corners and look again...

Comment: @AaronD What do you mean?

Comment: Put them both on the vertical sections of wire instead of where they are now.  But keep the connections the same.

Comment: Yes, but it looks different.  This is often useful to understand things that are drawn weird.

Comment: Alright, they should cancel out still? Have I changed things by doing so?

Comment: Haha we're commenting at the same time, this is a bit awkward thanks! I drew it that way to because it's a part of a larger circuit but I wanted to see how things would be in that orientation.

Comment: By the way, never actually do this with real components.  The two sources will never be exactly equal, so one of them could take the entire load if you're lucky, leaving the other idle.  Or you could get an unreasonably high current between them, not going to the load, that can melt wires or blow up batteries, if you're unlucky.  Again, don't do this for real unless you know for sure that your specific parts can handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVSxnd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I understand, thanks. But what if it was not re-arranged and forced in the same orientation as the original?  Would they differ?

Comment: Are my 3 circuits equivalent?  Do they all make the same connections?  How would they be different?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftHjS7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It should be evident now that the voltage across the load is 20V, and hence the current cannot be 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be getting confused on what happens when a series circuit is cut down the middle. When a series circuit is essentially split down the middle as it is in your diagram, then it is no longer in series. Now they are in parallel

[image: a busy cat]([![CircuitLab Schematic b3e6ns]

Elements are in series when they have the same current flowing through them. Since the circuit is broken up into several loops, clearly they do not all have the same currents

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two voltage sources in parallel with each other?

Since the two voltage sources are the same voltage, they are redundant.

If they were set to be *different* voltages, this would create a contradiction. If you connected two voltage supplies of different voltages in the real world, instead of a contradiction, you may have an explosion or an unpleasant burning smell!